# For loop and arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I am practicing for course work and wanted to make a simple code to cycle through each string in an array. However, what actually happens is that it displays every string in the array over and over instead of replacing the one colour for another. How do I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Arrays</title>
        <script>
            colours = [" Purple"," Blue"," Pink"," Red"," Green"];
            function change() {
                for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML += colours[i];
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>The colour is: <span id=hai></span></p>
        <button id="btn" onclick="change()">Change!</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```js
colours = [" Purple", " Blue", " Pink", " Red", " Green"];

function change() {
    for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML += colours[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<p>The colour is: <span id=hai></span></p>
<button id="btn" onclick="change()">Change!</button>
```

Comment: Here's a hint. Use a variable that contains the index of what element in the array is currently displayed. In your `change` function, increment that pointer (remembering to make it go back to 0 at the end of the array) and display the corresponding array value.

Comment: [Cycle through an array on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203798/cycle-through-an-array-on-click), [Looping through array using a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602292/looping-through-array-using-a-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuously loop through JavaScript text array onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843467/continuously-loop-through-javascript-text-array-onclick)

Answer (score 6):

This is because you're *appending* the `innerHTML` of the node, rather than simply setting it, like so:

```
document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML = colours[i];
```

However, I suspect that's still not quite what you want - I'm guessing you want a new color after every click, in which case the code ought to look something like:

```
var colours = [" Purple"," Blue"," Pink"," Red"," Green"];
var currentColourIndex = 0;
function change() {
    document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML = colours[++currentColourIndex % colours.length];
}
```

Edit: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hx0eyemm/)

Comment: Neat trick with the modulus. I never would have thought of that.

Comment: Good use of fake accounts

Comment: Next time **explain** better what you need. I grow downvotes even answering your exactly question

Answer (score 3):

You need an index, declared and initialized outside the change function:

```js
var actualIndex = 0,
    colours = [" Purple", " Blue", " Pink", " Red", " Green"];

function change() {
    actualIndex++;                 // increment
    actualIndex %= colours.length; // correct the range
    document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML = colours[actualIndex];
}
```

```html
<p>The colour is: <span id="hai"></span></p>
<button id="btn" onclick="change()">Change!</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as Thomas' answer.

Comment: not really, i keep the index low, the other answer increments until it never goes.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you do not need a for-loop: you want display just 1 color at time.

```js
var colours = [" Purple", " Blue", " Pink", " Red", " Green"];
var currentIndex = 0;

function change() {
  if(currentIndex >= colours.length) currentIndex = 0;
  document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML = colours[currentIndex++];
}
```

```html
<p>The colour is: <span id=hai></span></p>
<button id="btn" onclick="change()">Change!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop can't be used for your requirement. Use the below snippet.

```
    <script>
        colours = [" Purple"," Blue"," Pink"," Red"," Green"];
        var count=0;
        function change() {
        if(count==5){
            count=0;
        }
        document.getElementById("hai").innerHTML = colours[count];
        count++;
        }
    </script>
```